# Haskell: How to report validation errors from command line arguments to user with proper exit codes

Tags: haskell

I'm using `getOpt` to parse and validate the args provided by `getArgs`.

I chose to use the action based approach for `getOpt`, here are the types.

```hs
data Options = Options { afield :: foo, bfield :: bar}
type Action = Either String (Options -> Options)
```

Then I fold over the actions list on a default options record using,

```hs
evaluateActions :: Either [String] Options -> Action -> Either [String] Options
evaluateActions (Left errors) (Left err)      = Left $ err:errors
evaluateActions (Left errors) (Right _)       = Left errors
evaluateActions (Right _) (Left err)          = Left [err]
evaluateActions (Right option) (Right action) = Right $ action option
```

Afterwards I am left with the desired type `Either [String] Options`.
Upon error(s), I want to print the strings out and exit with the error code InvalidArgument.

```hs
printErrorsThenExit :: [String] -> ExitCode -> IO ()
printErrorsThenExit errs code =
  hPutStr stderr (concat errs) >>
  exitWith code
```

I am struggling to glue this together in my main function without writing something like the following which doesn't work with the types:

```hs
opts <- case result of
          Left errors   -> printErrorsThenExit errors illegalArgument  
          Right options -> return options
```

I have seen the `when` function but I don't think it helps since I need to unwrap the Either.

Anyone know how I can express failure process in Haskell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we have

```
exitWith :: ExitCode -> IO a
```

you can simply change your `printErrorsThenExit` type to

```
printErrorsThenExit :: [String] -> ExitCode -> IO a
                                               -- ^ --
```

The point is: if an IO action does not actually return (but exits the whole program) its type can be `IO a` for any `a`, claiming that it can fit any type.

Your `main` code should then just work as it is.